# VBA Loop Stuck when moving balances

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am working on a macro that runs through every sheet in a workbook excluding the page called "Summary" and moves ending balances to prior balances. It is supposed to check the value in a cell next to the the defined cell "Statement_Name". Depending on that value it either moves the balance or moves to the next sheet.

2 issues, the macro is not always recognizing what is in the cell to the right of "statement_Name" and it is not always moving to the next sheet. My gut feeling is that it's to do with having the same names for defined cells within each of the sheets but could be wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```vb
Sub PRIORTONEWBALANCE3()

Static FrequencyEntered As Boolean
Dim Frequency As String
Dim Statement_Name As String

    If Not FrequencyEntered Then
        Frequency = InputBox("Accounting cycle Q or SQ?", "Frequency") ' Ask the user for the frequency (semi or quarterly)
        FrequencyEntered = True
    End If
 

    Select Case ActiveSheet.Name
        Case "Summary"  ' Code to execute if the sheet is named "Summary"
            Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate 'Move to next sheet
 
                
        Case Else   ' Code to execute if the sheet is not any of the specified names      

                ActiveSheet.Range("Statement_Name").Offset(0, 1).Select
                If UCase(Frequency) = "Q" And InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, "Semi-Annual") Then
   
                            Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate 'Move to next sheet
                             Else
                                ActiveSheet.Range("Ending_Balance").Select
                                Selection.Copy
                                ActiveSheet.Range("Prior_Balance").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False 'Paste to ending balance
                                Selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
                                Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Clear Clipboard
                                Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + 1).Activate   'Move to next sheet
                     
                               End If
      
    End Select
End Sub
```

Tried a loop instead of a select case.

Answer (score 1):

Summary:

- Your code doesn't loop through your sheets
- Your code doesn't do anything with the cell next to the Statement_Name cell
- Multiple named ranges with the same name on different sheets is OK
- Using `ActiveSheet` and `Select` may let in unexpected errors, so reference your cells and sheets directly

> it is not always moving to the next sheet

Your code doesn't have anything that would *ever* move it to the next sheet.  The `.Activate` will make a new sheet visible, but your code isn't moving through each sheet.  If you want to loop through a bunch of sheets, you'll need some kind of looping structure.  Probably a [For Each loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement).  For example, the following code loops through all sheets in a workbook, and prints their names if they are not named "Sheet1".

```
Private Sub ForEachDemo()

    Dim wkSheet As Worksheet
    For Each wkSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    
        If wkSheet.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
            
            Debug.Print wkSheet.Name
            
        End If
    
    Next wkSheet

End Sub
```

> the macro is not always recognizing what is in the cell to the right of "statement_Name"

Your code doesn't do anything with the cell after it selects it.

See your line `ActiveSheet.Range("Statement_Name").Offset(0, 1).Select`?  What happens after it?  You enter an `If` statement.
On the first branch of your `If` statement (`If UCase(Frequency) = "Q" And InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, "Semi-Annual") Then`) all the code does is activate a new sheet.
On the second branch of your `If` statement the code now selects another cell. Either way, nothing is done with the first cell you selected.

> My gut feeling is that it's to do with having the same names for defined cells within each of the sheets but could be wrong.

This is good intuition, but I don't believe it's causing your problems here.  Or, not directly at least.  There is no problem using the same names for different ranges on different sheets.  After all, we have a cell named "A1" on every sheet!  You just need to make sure you're selecting the right range on each sheet.  That is why you're using `ActiveSheet`, but we can make this more robust when we loop through all sheets.  The `ActiveSheet` is just whatever sheet the user can interact with at the moment.  VBA doesn't have to "see" the sheet like a person to interact with it, so we will bypass this by referencing the sheets directly.

With these ideas in mind, we can rewrite parts of the code to do what you want.

```
Private Sub Rewrite()

    Static FrequencyEntered As Boolean
    Dim Frequency As String

    ' Ask the user for the frequency (semi or quarterly)
    If Not FrequencyEntered Then
        Frequency = InputBox("Accounting cycle Q or SQ?", "Frequency")
        FrequencyEntered = True
    End If
    
    ' You need to assign some value to Statement_Name, or this code will error out
    Dim Statement_Name As String
     
    ' Loop through all worksheets in this workbook
    Dim wksheet As Worksheet
    For Each wksheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    
        ' Ignore the sheet named "Summary"
        If wksheet.Name <> "Summary" Then
        
            ' Ignore the sheet if "Q" frequency was selected
            If UCase(Frequency) <> "Q" Then
            
                wksheet.Range("Statement_Name").Offset(0, 1).Select
                
                ' Ignore the sheet if "Semi-Annual" is in the selected cell
                If InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, "Semi-Annual") = 0 Then

                    ' Get the value of the ending balance
                    Dim endingBalance As Double
                    endingBalance = wksheet.Range("Ending_Balance").Value
                    
                    ' Put the ending balance value in the prior balance cell
                    wksheet.Range("Prior_Balance").Value = endingBalance
                    
                    ' Change the number format of the prior balance cell
                    wksheet.Range("Prior_Balance").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
            
                End If
            End If
        End If
      
    Next wksheet
    
End Sub
```

As with any question, it's impossible to say if this will solve problems caused by other parts of your code that aren't shown.  But I beleive your direct questions and issues are addressed here.

Answer (score 0):

- Iterate through all worksheets except for `Summary`.
- If a sheet meets certain criteria, copy the value from `Ending_Balance` to `Prior_Balance`.

*The criteria depend on user input*

> If the user input is "Q," check if the keyword cell (the cell next to the cell named "Statement_Name") contains the word "Quarter."

> If the user input is "SQ," check if the keyword cell contains the word "Semi-Annual."

*Note:* You may need modify criteria as needed.

```vb
Sub PRIORTONEWBALANCE3()
    Static FrequencyEntered As Boolean
    Dim Frequency As String, sFreq As String
    Dim Statement_Name As String
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    If Not FrequencyEntered Then
        Frequency = InputBox("Accounting cycle Q or SQ?", "Frequency") 
        FrequencyEntered = True
    End If
    For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sht.Name <> "Summary" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            sFreq = Sht.Range("Statement_Name").Offset(0, 1).Value
            On Error GoTo 0
            If (Frequency = "Q" And InStr(1, sFreq, "Quarter", vbTextCompare) > 0) Or _
                (Frequency = "SQ" And InStr(1, sFreq, "Semi-Annual", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
                With Sht.Range("Prior_Balance")
                    .Value = Sht.Range("Ending_Balance").Value
                    .NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```